# MTA poor reputation

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, reverse-dns

I'm facing MTA poor reputation and I'm fighting against it since days without success. MTA poor reputation had plenty topics so I verify/modify many aspect of my configuration such as:

- Verify blacklist IP
- Add reverse DNS on my ISP
- Match the smtp banner
- Add SPF allowing my smtp and webserver for my domain

Everything seems good from mxtoolsbox tools but ...

Talosintelligence rate the email reputation as poor. Since I make change on my SPF record, this reputation change from poor to neutral only for one day. There is something I forgot or don't understand and that why I post this topic here if anybody face and resolve this problem.

I investigate further and I think the problem can become from the DNS configuration:
actually, MX record isn't FQDN, it show as: x.x.x.x.mydomainname.com (same for the reverse).
Du to microsft [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/300171/you-are-unable-to-send-or-receive-smtp-messages-from-certain-internet) (old but seems good), I think I add to change my MX record as mailserver.mydomainname.com (and the reverse as well). 
But I had to add an A record. My question is that I had to add it on my ISP DNS ?
mailserver.mydomainname.com A x.x.x.x  should be good ?

Thanks you for reading me and for the help
regards,

Comment: Gerald, thanks for the  shared topic but it doesn't help me for my question (about FQDN on MX or not). Anyway, I learn a lot from it, thanks

Comment: Yes. Adding `@ MX 10 mailserver.mydomain.com.` and `mailserver.mydomain.com.  A   x.x.x.x` should be good.

Comment: Thanks you Tom. Before making new DNS entry, I just see that smtp banner and DNS entry wasn't resolvable (but mxtoolsbox tell me it was good match). So now it is. I will keep this topic updated if it work.

Comment: DNS modification didn't resolve the issue. But I found a website who show an error with a RFC: postmaster@domain wasn't reachable. So, I add it on my smtp proxy and my echange. Everything looks fine now: no more email reputation and no more error 554. Thanks for the help.